# How Can I get rowcount with formatted numbers in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, `df.shape` returns `(5671619, 9)` in pandas. I want `(5,671,619, 9)`. I've tried `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format` but I think that's only for what's in the dataframe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.shape returns a tuple of values completely separate from the underlying dataframe, so you have to format it separately. You can unpack the tuple with the `*` operator

```
df.shape

(1996, 12)

"({:,}, {:,})".format(*df.shape)

'(1,996, 12)'
```

Note that this gives it as a string, and that the extra comma placement can make it look a little strange at first glance

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson!